# How to stop refreshing page after ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, refresh

I am unable to stop refreshing page after ajax call. I have tried by putting e.preventDefault(); and return false; as well but again my page is refreshing.

I dont know what is the problem with the code or something. Please help me to stop refreshing page after ajax call. solving this issue would be a great help for me. Thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#loginForm').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = {
            'uname'  : $('#uname').val(),
            'pwd'    :      $('#pwd').val()
        };
        $.ajax({
            type        : "POST",
            url         : "getresults.php", 
            data        : formData
        }).done(function(data) {
              alert(data+"This is working");
        }).fail(function(data) {
              alert("This is not working");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Is `#loginForm` a form or a button? Could you also provide your HTML code please?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Is the id `#loginForm` pointing to a form? If yes you need to listen to the submit event instead of click. If you really need to listen to the click event, you have to bind the event to the submit button or whatever triggers the `form.submit()`.

Try something like this:

```
$('#loginForm').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation(); // only neccessary if something above is listening to the (default-)event too

    [YOUR CODE GOES HERE]
});
```

This should do the trick for you.

Comment: `e.stopPropagation();` is useless here, you just need to prevent default behaviour ;)

Comment: oh you are right ... it was just my usual way to capture events and prevent them from usual behavior (i'm used to stop them from bubbeling up) ... i quickly update my answer ;)

Comment: @hugohabel and others: sorry. you are right it should be "on submit". but after changing that also unable to stop refreshing. page is refreshing after a moment.

Comment: Hi all,
Thanks for your response.
I just extracted only form code and submitted i got my result without refreshing the page.
There is some problem with the my other code in same page.
During my research i got to know that if there is any issue in code, page will refresh on submit. Right ?

Answer (score 52):

Adding `type="button"` attribute to button solved my problem. Otherwise it was interpreted as submit operation.

Comment: I added it, my page still refresh.

Answer (score 21):

This was happening to me earlier tonight, and I found my way to this question - This might be a long shot but I realized what my issue was and figure this might help someone in the future dealing with this.

Are you using something like `live-server` locally or some other form of script that intelligently refreshes local code if new files appear in the same working folder? If so - the page is refreshing not because of your code, but because whatever ajax you called manipulated the folder you were working in resulting in the page 'updating'.

Comment: Thank you! Still not quite sure what live-server thought was 'updating' on my page, but switching to static-server from live-server prevented the 'postback'

Comment: This worked in my case, I use live-server, and I never would have thought that was the cause. As soon as I turned it off, it stopped.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this hint!! As already mentioned, I never would have found this as reason as well..

Answer (score 9):

I think just adding return false after the on click function will stop the page from refreshing

Answer (score 1):

This can happen when you have turned on *live server* extension or something like that refresh html pages.

Comment: An example of how to check this would be useful.

Comment: This was causing my problem with the vs code live server extension.