# Ajax refreshing page in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm using Ajax to pass some data to a Controller and save to database, and it works, the issue that is refreshing the page with every POST and I need to prevent that.

Ajax:

```
function AddComment(commet, auto) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/bff/SaveComment',
        data: { id: idParte, commenta: commet, autoriza: auto },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (correct) {
            $("#win1").show().kendoWindow({
                width: "300px",
                height: "100px",
                modal: true,
                title: "Added"
            });
        },
        errror: function(inc) {
        }
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SaveComment(int id, string commenta, string autoriza)
{
    // Some logic here
    return Json("");
}
```

Tried [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27759438/1684134) with correct.preventDefault(); but didn't work

Is there a way to do it?

**EDITED:**

This is my HTML:

```
<form role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Commentario:")
    <textarea id="Comment" style="resize:none;" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Guardar" onclick="AddComment(Comment.value,'Comentario')" />
</div>
</form>
```

**EDITED 2:**

Fixed by changing type="submit" for **type="button"** Thanks to [Hasta Pasta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3787353/hasta-pasta)

Comment: How is this method called from the user action? Is it bound in a jquery click? Javascript within the href? This is the place where the page behavior is interrupting.

Comment: Could you explain the code flow? when is  AddComment function called? Also add this after url in ajax call. It is true by default anyhow worth a try. async : true,

Comment: It's called in a button that read a textarea:

<textarea id="Comment" style="resize:none;" class="form-control"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Guardar" onclick="AddComment(Comment.value,'Comentario')" /> @JoelEtherton

Comment: Add preventDefault(); to your click handler not your ajax function. It should be something like btn.on("click", function(e){ e.preventDefault(); addComment(comment,auto); });

Comment: remove type= "submit" and make type = "button". Submit will try to post the form to the controller and hence refresh the page

Comment: Refer to this to understand difference with Submit action. It will help you resolve your issue as well. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759380/how-to-stop-refreshing-page-after-ajax-call Also make sure you dont have any ajaxSetup done on application. Hasta Pasta is right replacing submit by button will be easy fix.

Comment: Worked with button instead submit. Awesome!!! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

i think you should put return false; after the ajax request

```
function AddComment(commet, auto) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/bff/SaveComment',
        data: { id: idParte, commenta: commet, autoriza: auto },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (correct) {
            $("#win1").show().kendoWindow({
                width: "300px",
                height: "100px",
                modal: true,
                title: "Added"
            });
        },
        error: function(inc) {
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

based on you need to return false as you sayed :)

```
<form role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Commentario:")
    <textarea id="Comment" style="resize:none;" class="form-control"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" value="Guardar" onclick="return AddComment(Comment.value,'Comentario')" />
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: could you please post your html also ?

Comment: Based on the comment by OP, this is the correct answer, but it is still missing an element. The onclick also needs to return false this way: `onclick="return AddComment(Comment.value,'Comentario')"`

Comment: i just edit the answer to be complete with your edit :) on button