# Delay php-action for a form with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I do trigger my contactform with that js-code here:

```
$("#trigger_kontakt").click(sendContactMail);

function sendContactMail() {
    var name = $('#target_kontakt input[name="name"]').val();
    var email = $('#target_kontakt input[name="email"]').val();

    if (name.length>3 && email.length>3) {
                $(".sw_normal").addClass('passiv');
        $(".sw_danke").addClass('active');
        // I need help with that block here:
button.delay(10000).queue(function() {
            $.post('contact.php',{name:name, email:email});
                  });
        }
    }
```

And that worked nicely when I had the post-action at first block of the chain but the success-message doesn't get displayed then really visible of course. Therefore I used the delay-function for the post-action, but now my form doesn't get even send anymore. So I am asking for help on the delay-action. What do I need to do there?

Comment: Why would you want to delay an AJAX call (or the result of the call) by ten seconds?

Comment: When you say "the success message doesn't get displayed" maybe it's because you aren't waiting for the AJAX response before trying to display it?  Can you show your code that is supposed to display the message?

Comment: I want to delay the post-action so the user can see my "Thank-you"-post for a while. Of course a better solution would be to not "reload" the page at all but that is the code I do have right now.

Comment: @BizzyBob of course: It's simple. I just trigger some blocks:     $(".sw_normal").addClass('passiv');
        $(".sw_danke").addClass('active');

And I guess they do get displayed but as the page gets loaded newly due to the post-action no one can see them :)

Comment: If the page is refreshing, you can prevent it using preventDefault()

Comment: @BizzyBob coudl you please figure that one out a bit more?

Comment: See solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759380/how-to-stop-refreshing-page-after-ajax-call