# Preventing a page loading with a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html

How can i prevent the whole page loading? At the moment when i select an option from the drop down menu, the page reloads regardless of what i try. I'm not sure if its because you can't stop a 'change' event, or if my ajax is wrong.

```
<form action="" method="get" id="rati">
  <select name="value" onchange="this.form.submit()">
    <option value="default" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="Authors">Authors</option>
    <option value="Papers">Papers</option>
    <option value="countries">Countries</option>
    <option value="Organisations">Organisations</option>
  </select>
</form>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("[name='value']").on('change', function () {
      e.preventDeault();
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "localhost:1234/",
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: "json",
        data: $("#rati").serialize(),
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759380/how-to-stop-refreshing-page-after-ajax-call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Best practice, bind event using javascript, not within your HTML.
2. You are already assigning the event when you are calling `jQuery.on`.
3. Doing `onchange="this.form.submit()` will cause  reload, submitting a form on change will submit the current page. You should follow best the practice and also assign your `submit` event on your form using jQuery `$form.on('submit', cb)` or better vanillaJS `form.addEventListener('submit', cb, false)`.
4. You are using the wrong `event` from `ready` instead of `on`.
5. Do not use `id` unless on your `<form />` unless you want to start by restricting it's presence by 1 per page for some weird reasons.
6. jQuery is obsolete, you should drop it in new projects. Selectors now exist in modern browsers and their animations use too much javascript and no CSS3.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("[name='value']").on('change', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "localhost:1234/",
      crossDomain: true,
      dataType: "json",
      data: $("#rati").serialize(),
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get" id="rati">
  <select name="value">
    <option value="default" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="Authors">Authors</option>
    <option value="Papers">Papers</option>
    <option value="countries">Countries</option>
    <option value="Organisations">Organisations</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

Comment: thanks that seems to solve the issue to some extent, interestingly i'm getting the following error

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:1234/?value=Papers' from origin 'http://localhost:1234' has been blocked by CORS policy

Comment: The CORS issue is another issue. If you are referencing to the example, it is absolutely normal because jsfiddle does not host the server you are using in your own snippet. I added a few recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

You have `preventDeault`, but it should be `preventDefault`. Looks like a simple typo.