# How to avoid page refresh after the alert came for wrong entry in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, ajax

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>Captcha Implementation</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container" style="width: 600px">
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id="message"></div>
                    <h4 align="center">Submit the word you see below:</h4>
                    <p id="captImg" align="center">
                        <img src="image.php" id="captcha_image"/>
                    </p>
                    <!-- <p align="center">Can't read the image? click <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="refreshCaptcha">here</a> to refresh.</p> -->
                    <form action="index.php" method="post" id="captch_form" name="captch_form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Enter the Captcha</label>
                            <input type="text" name="captcha_word" id="captcha_word" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="" autocomplete="off"/>
                            <div id="message" align="center" class='text-danger'></div>
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Contact Number</label>
                            <input type="text" name="contact_number" id="contact_number" class="form-control" value="" autocomplete="off"/>
                            
                        </div>
                        
                        <div class="form-group" align="center">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="SUBMIT" onclick="captcha_submit()"/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

<script>
    function captcha_submit()
    {
        var Data = $("#captch_form").serializeArray();
        console.log(Data); 
        $.ajax(
            {
                url : "action.php?name=captcha_save",
                type: "POST",
                data : Data,
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#message').html(data);
                }
            });
            $("#message").slideDown("slow");
            e.preventDefault(); 
    }
</script>

<?php
    $host = "localhost";
    $database = "pmcrb_ambabajaj";
    $user = "root";
    $password= "";
    $db = $database;
    
    $con = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$db);
    
    $Action = @$_GET['name'];
    
    if($Action == 'captcha_save')
    {
        $captcha_word = @$_POST['captcha_word'];
        $contact_number = @$_POST['contact_number'];
        $created_date = time();
        
        if($captcha_word == '')
        {?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
                Please Enter Captcha.
            </div>
        <?php }
        /*else if($captcha_word == $_SESSION['captcha_code'])
        {?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <strong style="color:#fff;text-align:center;font-size:14px;font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif;margin-left:50px;">Warning!</strong> Invalid Captcha Code
            </div>
        <?php }*/
        else if($contact_number == '')
        {?>
            <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <strong style="color:#fff;text-align:center;font-size:14px;font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif;margin-left:50px;">Warning!</strong> Please Enter Contact Number
            </div>
        <?php }
        else
        {
            $sql = "insert into pm1captcha(`created_date`,`contact_number`,`captcha_word`)values('$created_date','$contact_number','$captcha_word')";
            $qry = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            ?>
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <strong style="color:#fff;text-align:center;font-size:14px;font-family:Times New Roman, Times, serif;margin-left:50px;">Success!</strong> Data Saved Successfully
            </div>
        <?php }
        
    }
?>
```

I have written some to code to save the captcha details to database table, the data is saving correctly but the page is getting refresh every time if the filed is left empty. How to avoid the page refresh after the alert came every time in php. Can anyone please help me. here i written html code in index.php page and php code is written in action.php page

Comment: While this is not related to your quest, I noticed your insert statement makes your site vulnerable to SQL injection attack. Search for 'prevent SQL injection in PHP' to find how to prevent it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop refreshing page after ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27759380/how-to-stop-refreshing-page-after-ajax-call)

Comment: Thanku so much for your reply, it finally worked.